# Prefijos Telefónicos

Tags: javascript

Debo crear una función llamada `validarPrefijo` que reciba un número por parámetro. Deberá:

Generar un objeto desde dos arreglos dados. Deberá tener como propiedades, los números de prefijos, y como valor, el país correspondiente a cada prefijo.
ejemplo :

{
54: “Argentina”,
55: ”Brasil”,
56: ”Ecuador”,
57: ”Bolivia”
}

Validar si los dos primeros números del pasado por parámetro existen en el objeto de prefijos telefónicos. En caso de ser correcto, deberá retornar “Este número pertenece a X”.
En caso de ser incorrecto deberá retornar “El número no pertenece a nuestros países”

Ejemplo:
validarPrefijo(“5412345678”) debe retornar “Este número pertenece a Argentina”
validarPrefijo(“5712345678”) debe retornar “Este número pertenece a Bolivia”
validarPrefijo(“8012345678”) debe retornar “El número no pertenece a nuestros países”

debes utilizar las siguientes variables:
var prefijos = [54, 55, 56, 57, 58]
var paises = ["argentina", "brasil", "chile", "colombia", "venezuela"]

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo o quieres que te den la solución sin más? Para poder dar una solución es preferible ver que has intentado, eso da una idea de tu manejo del lenguaje y de las explicaciones que necesitas.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque aquí no se hacen tareas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mira este código:

```js
var prefijos = [54, 55, 56, 57, 58];
var paises = ["argentina", "brasil", "chile", "colombia", "venezuela"];

// Crea el objeto de tipo { 54: “Argentina”, 55: ”Brasil”, 56: ”Ecuador”, 57: ”Bolivia” }
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
                prefijos.map((pre, i) => 
                    [pre, paises[i][0].toUpperCase() + paises[i].slice(1)]
                )
            );

function validarPrefijo (num) {
  // Obtiene el pais a partir del numero de prefijo
  const pais = obj[String(num).substring(0, 2)];
  // Verifica si existe el pais
  return pais ? "Este número pertenece a " + pais : 
                "El número no pertenece a nuestros países";
}

console.log(validarPrefijo("5412345678"));
console.log(validarPrefijo("5712345678"));
console.log(validarPrefijo("8012345678"));
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) la documentación de **`Object.fromEntries()`**, que tal vez pueda ser un poco confusa, pero básicamente lo que hace es crear un objeto a partir de una serie de arrays anidados.

Comment: muchas gracias Alexandro Palacios ya leyendo la documentación la agrego a mi libreta de estudios

Comment: y tambien prodria trabajar el objeto con el CharCodeAt() ??

Comment: Si lo dices por el "paises[i][0]", lo puedes reemplazar por el "paises[i].charAt(0)". En cambio charCodeAt() devuelve el código ascii del caracter.

Comment: ok entendido gracias!!!